# What is a good way for a designer to create a 9-Patch Image for me -- Without knowledge of 9-Patch

Tags: android, ios, workflow, splash-screen, nine-patch

I am on a small mobile application development team and we have decided that we are going to use a 9-Patch Image for android Splash Screens.

For iOS this easy - the designer is going to use this template  --http://davidlillo.com/ios-splash-screen-template-psd/

In photoshop, the designer can easily create the iOS splash screen, generate all the sizes and hand it off to me - The Developer.

How can I adopt a workflow similar to this one for creating 9-Patch Splash Screens for android? I would like my designers to use a template like this, but I cannot find one that will do a 9Patch.

I have looked into many online tools that generate 9-Patch, but we don't want to rely on somebody else's web service or upload our proprietary images to who-knows-where in the cloud.

The problem with Draw 9-Patch command line tool, and other tools on GitHub is that these tools are for Developers. I don't want a designer to have install anything on their computer to generate image sizes.

Ideally we would like to create a Splash Screen image ***one time*** in Photoshop and generate all of the sizes for iOS (we have this already) along with a 9-Patch image for all of the android sizes.

Does a solution like this exist out there? It would be a nice if there was a Photoshop Template that we could use where we would make the image one time generate all the sizes for both android and iOS. If not, can someone please describe a workflow they use where the designer is responsible for creating the 9-Patch image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice tool out there for quick 9 path generation on this link:

[Simple Nine-patch Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Comment: I am aware of this tool, and thank you for your comment. We really do not want to rely on an online tool